# Why doesn't TicTacToe minimax work properly

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I made this tictactoe a long time ago and decided to add AI option today. However for no obvious to me reason it just doesn't work even though I converted it from working javascript code.

Removed some irrelevent to the problem functions

```
    def minimax(self, is_max):
        if self.won():
            return 1 if self.winner() == 'O' else -1

        if self.draw():
            return 0

        if is_max:
            best_score = float('-inf')
            for i in range(9):
                if self.valid_move(i):
                    self.board[i] = 'O'
                    score = self.minimax(False)
                    self.board[i] = ' '
                    best_score = max(best_score, score)
            return best_score
        else:
            best_score = float('inf')
            for i in range(9):
                if self.valid_move(i):
                    self.board[i] = 'X'
                    score = self.minimax(True)
                    self.board[i] = ' '
                    best_score = min(best_score, score)
            return best_score

    def best_move(self):
        best_score = float('-inf')
        move = 0
        for i in range(9):
            if self.valid_move(i):
                self.board[i] = 'O'
                score = self.minimax(False)
                self.board[i] = ' '

                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                    move = i

        return move

    def move_ai(self):
        self.board[self.best_move()] = self.current_player()
        self.current_move += 1
        self.show_board()
```

Comment: Would you add the original JavaScript code you were referencing?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem statement.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make the correct moves. I really can't tell more than that.

Comment: https://github.com/CodingTrain/website/blob/master/CodingChallenges/CC_154_Tic_Tac_Toe_Minimax/P5/minimax.js  - Here is the js code I was referring to. I have made changes to some parts as I had to make it compatable with my code but the structure is the same

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: I tried it. It works fine (in the sense that the computer will win when you let it, and won't let you win ever). It does have the standard quirk for a first-time tic-tac-toe minimax. There may be a flaw in the code that you didn't show (I had to fill in a lot of pieces).

Comment: Could you send your code? I guess the problem is in what I didn't show even though it worked for 2 players.

Comment: Yep found the problem. I had a function that relies on self.current_move but thats not updated during minimax recursion.